# The homomorphism between polynomial over a ring and a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let F be a field and choose an element $u \in F$. Consider the function $\epsilon_u:F[x]\rightarrow F$ given by $$\epsilon_u(a_nx^n+...+a_0)=a_nu^n+...+a_0$$

I am asked to show that this is surjective but not injective, as well as finding its kernel.

My idea is that this function will just send every element in $F$ to itself, hence the surjectivity. Since there is this one-to-one correspondence between the part of the range and the entire domain, the function cannot possibly be injective. I am not sure if this is the right idea or how to formalize it, and I am also not sure how to find the kernel.

Comment: Much simpler: as the evaluation map is a ring homomorphism, find the kernel.

Comment: Will it be just 0?

Comment: If it's injective. But is it?

Comment: No it is not injective so the kernel won't be just 0,  but I am not sure I follow exactly how you find out what it is

Comment: The function can't send elements to themselves, because the domain and codomain are different spaces. Normally, when we talk about F(x), we're talking about some fixed F, and looking what happens when we vary x. This problem asks you to consider the opposite: x is fixed, and F is allowed to vary. So if x is fixed, what sort of different values can we get by varying F? Suppose I first pick an x and a y, and then you get to pick any F you want. Are you guaranteed to be able to find an F such that F(x) = y? What happens if y = 0?

Comment: @Acccumulation Wouldn't any such function send the constant polynomials to a corresponding element in $F$?

Comment: You're right. However, strictly speaking, a constant polynomial is not an element of the base ring, but they may be identified.

Answer (score 3):

Surjective: consider what happens to CONSTANT polynomials (polynomials of degree zero) under your mapping. Not injective: Consider the two polynomials $p(x) = x$ (of degree $1$) and $q(x) = u$ (a polynomial of degree zero, i.e. a constant). Are $p$ and $q$ equal? What are their images under the mapping?

Kernel: a polynomial $p(x)$ is mapped to $0$ when $p(u) = 0$. This is equivalent to $p(x)$ being divisible by $x-u$. The kernel is the principal ideal generated by $x-u$.

Answer (score 0):

For a polynomial ring over a commutative ring $A$, you have the equivalence
$$\forall u\in A\;\forall f\in A [X],\quad(f(u)=0\iff f\;\text{is divisible by}\; X-u).$$

Indeed, let's divide $f(X)$ by $X-u$. We get
$$f(X)=q(X)(X-u)+r,\qquad r\in A. $$
Clearly, $\;f(u)=0\iff r=0$.

Comment: Could you explain why?

Comment: Do you know *Euclidean division*?

Comment: Yes! I know what that is

Comment: OK, I'll add an explanation.